# Как сделать, чтобы при смене слайда блоки прилетали с боков к центру?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую слайдер bxslider.js. Можно как-то на нем реализовать, чтоб контент слайда съезжал с боков к центру? Или, может, есть другой метод?

**Из комментария:**
Сам слайд вмещает 2 блока. Нужно, чтоб они при смене слайда прилетали с боков к центру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Что вы подразумеваете под фразой "контент слайда съезжающий до центра с двух половин"?

Comment: сам слайд (http://c2n.me/3x3t4AT) вмещает 2 блока, нужно чтоб они при смене слайда прилетали с сторон к центру